# Backbonejs - view initialize not show the collections

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to fetch the `json` objects from local json file. the file contains an array with 2 data.

my views `initialize` method not giving any result.

what i the mistake I made here? any one help me?

here is my code :

```
var Theater = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}

Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Theater.Models.Movie,
    url: "scripts/data/movies.json",
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Movies initialize");
    }
});

Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log( 'view', this.collection, this.collection.models.length ) //gives  no results
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
         this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log("render") 
        console.log(this.collection.length); nothing consoled
    }
})

Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "defaultRoute"
    },

    defaultRoute: function () {
    console.log("defaultRoute");
    Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies()
    new Theater.Views.Movies({ collection: Theater.movies }); 
    Theater.movies.fetch().done(function(){
        console.log(Theater.movies.length) //2
    });

}
})

var appRouter = new Theater.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch()` won't trigger `reset` event unless you pass `{reset: true}`. You should bind to `sync` event instead.

And it is a good idea to use `listenTo` for binding events:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
```

Answer (score -1):

You ll have to put  `this.render();` in `initialize: function () {}`

`render()` does not get called automatically.

Comment: But I am calling on `reset` it should work for me see : `this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);`